# Getting data From a java DB with SQL Using ResultSet

Tags: java, sql

I created a method to get the values from a database in java using SQL and store the information in a `ResultSet` and then use a `while` loop to store the information in a `RentSendItem` and store all those items in an `ArrayList` called `sendList` but when I try to run it, it gives me the error:

> 'ResultSet not open. Operation 'getString' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is off'

This is my class:

```
public void getDataFromDB() {
    System.out.println("Wordk");
    //connecting
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet name = statement.executeQuery("SELECT firstname,surname FROM CUSTOMER");
        ResultSet titles = statement.executeQuery("Select Title,Category From ADDDVD ");
        System.out.println(name.getString("firstname"));
        System.out.println("2");
        while (name.next()) {
            String fullName = name.getString("firstname") + " " + name.getString("surname");
            RentSendItem item = new RentSendItem(name.getString("firstname") + name.getString("surname"), titles.getString("Category"), titles.getString("title"));
            sendList.add(item);
        }
        System.out.println("3");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So just want to know what am I doing wrong and will this class do what I want it to do. If you could maybe help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: comment below line and check 

System.out.println(name.getString("firstname"));

Comment: try once with the comment above the line and let me know what you will get.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.

1. You can't call method `getString()` of interface `java.sql.ResultSet` before you call method `next()`. First call method `next()` and if that method returns "true", then you can call method `getString()`.
2. You also need to call method `next()` on `titles`.
3. You can't call `getString()` twice on the same column on the same row.

Compare the below with your code.

```java
public void getDataFromDB() {
    System.out.println("Wordk");
    // connecting
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        System.out.println("1");
        ResultSet name = statement.executeQuery("SELECT firstname,surname FROM CUSTOMER");
        ResultSet titles = statement.executeQuery("Select Title,Category From ADDDVD ");
        System.out.println("2");
        while (name.next()) {
            String firstname = name.getString("firstname");
            String surname = name.getString("surname");
            String fullName = firstname + " " + surname;
            if (titles.next()) {
                RentSendItem item = new RentSendItem(fullName,
                                                     titles.getString("Category"),
                                                     titles.getString("title"));
                sendList.add(item);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("3");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, the following are not problems but recommendations.

1. In the `catch` block, it usually preferable to print the entire stack trace rather than just the error message.
2. You should close the `Connection` and `Statement` once you no longer need them. In the code above, I have used [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)